# Disable field in Django forms do not fetch the original value

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to disable the field input for update from my `view`

```
class FoodListView(FormListView):
form_class = forms.FoodForm
context_object_name = "foods"

def get_queryset(self):
    return Food.objects.all()

def get_create_form(self):
    form = super().get_create_form()
    form.fields["is_active"].initial = True
    form.fields["is_active"].disabled = True

    return form

def get_update_form(self, obj):
    form = super().get_update_form(obj)
    form.fields["is_active"].disabled = True
    return form

class FoodUpdateView(BaseUpdateView):
form_class = forms.FoodForm

def get_queryset(self):
    return Food.objects.all()

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance_form = self.form_class(self.get_object(), instance=self.get_object())
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my form

```
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ("name", "image", "price", "desc", "is_active")
```

But when I update, it doesn't retain the original value of the active status of the object to be updated.

I also tried `form.fields["is_active"].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'` but it still doesn't retain the value.

Is there any way I can disable it but upon update, it will retain the original value of this specific field? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your form and view to the question?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? In what view are you using this?

Comment: I've already updated the details. Thanks!

Comment: Is it `FoodListView` or `FoodUpdateView` that you are having issues with? In `FoodUpdateView.form_valid` you're passing the instance to the form class twice?

Comment: When I click update, other details will be saved properly, but the `is_active` value is not retained. If the original value is `true` , after update, it will be saved as `false`

Comment: I tried to remove the disabled property in the `get_update_form`, and it will function well. But when it is set to disable, it will reset the value of the field.

Comment: Disabled fields will not be posted in the request, you could try hiding the field instead?

Comment: I see. I'll just hide it then. I thought disabled fields' values can still be fetched. Thanks!